# not able to boot sda

Tags: boot

I was using Ubuntu 12.04.1 64bit, but I'm not able to boot /dev/sda. I tried to install grub, but I couldn't.

My questions are

1. Do I have to re-install.
2. Can I fix the "/dev/sda" as before i used.

I put `cat` and `fdisk -l`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004c895

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000bee1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0c1b08eb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: First, you should post any error messages you are getting. Second, from your output it looks as if sda is completely unformatted, I see no partitoins.

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen when GRUB can not loading properly or some files are missing or can not accessing at loading time so try to repair your GRUB by Boot Repair:-

$ grub-install -v ( to check GRUB version of ubuntu and here is GRUB file:- /boot/grub/grub.cfg )

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

$ boot-repair ( start the boot-repair )
and see advanced options at:-
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

It will reinstall and repair your GRUB.

Comment: thank you for reply quickly and I'm sorry my reply late.

Comment: i can not mount /dev/sda. I guess necessary to format and install again.